# NIntegrate:eincr error

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve this expression in Mathematica with the function NIntegrate:

```
    NIntegrate[(Abs[Subscript[δ, 1]-0.0675-Subscript[δ, 2]]EllipticE[-((4*0.1516*
    0.1516)/(Subscript[δ, 1]-0.0675-Subscript[δ, 2])^2)])/(7.2*6.3*2π^2*
    8.85418782*10^-12*((Subscript[δ, 1]-0.0675-Subscript[δ, 2])^2+(0.3032)^2)
    Sqrt[(Subscript[δ, 1]-0.0675-Subscript[δ, 2])^2]),{Subscript[δ, 1],
    -3.6,3.6},{Subscript[δ, 2],-3.15,3.15}]
```

However, when I try to solve it Mathematica first gives me this error:

> NIntegrate::slwcon:
>
> Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the
>   following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly 
>   oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

And then this one:

> NIntegrate::eincr:
>
> The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 10000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 5.338400038656212`*^10 and 2.8453968527047453`*^9 for the integral and error estimates.

What should I do to solve these errors? Also are these affecting the output of my expression?

Comment: Using mathematica 10.0.1 on a mac I get `4.47595*10^10`

Comment: In your previous question I showed how to write these kind of functions in a much more readable style for posting at the site. Please revisit my answer

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @belisarius Should I edit my expression by using functions?

Comment: You should comment on the answers you receive. Also, if they are right, you should upvote/accept. If they are wrong you should explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[d1_, d2_] = (Abs[
      d1 - 0.0675 - 
       d2] EllipticE[-((4*0.1516*0.1516)/(d1 - 0.0675 - 
            d2)^2)])/(7.2*6.3*2 \[Pi]^2*8.85418782*10^-12*((d1 - 0.0675 - 
          d2)^2 + (0.3032)^2) Sqrt[(d1 - 0.0675 - d2)^2]);

Plot3D[f[d1, d2], {d1, -3.6, 3.6}, {d2, -3.15, 3.15}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 101, PlotRange -> {0, 5*^10}]
```

[image]

There are discontinuities in the integrand.

Comment: Do these discontinuities affect the output and make these errors? If so, why do they affect the output and how can I fix it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Starior I believe Bob is suggesting that the integral diverges to infinity, which I think it does.  Since the integrand seems to be positive, I don't believe there is anything you can do.  Could there be an error in your setup?  (Note that `Abs[d1 - 0.0675 - d2]` and `Sqrt[(d1 - 0.0675 - d2)^2]` cancel each other out.  The integral still diverges, of course, but it made me wonder if there was a mistake somewhere.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I couldn't find out which part of the integrand makes it diverges to infinity. Can you tell me which part causes this?

Comment: @Starior, near the line `u = (d1 - 0.0675 - d2) = 0`, the integrand is asymptotically `k EllipticE[ -c / u^2]`, where `k` and `c` are positive constants, and its integral diverges over any region containing `u = 0`.  Alternatively, plot `f[d1, d2] (d1 - 0.0675 - d2)` and note it has bounded variation, which implies that the function behaves like ~ `1 / (d1 - 0.0675 - d2)` near the discontinuity.